# What does this gdb error mean? I'm getting this right after printing a line, and I have other code before it uses strlen

Tags: c

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2_pminub () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-sse2-pminub.S:38
38              movdqu  (%rdi), %xmm1

Comment: It means invalid memory was accessed. We can't say much more without seeing a complete code example. So please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There's not a great deal of information in the question but the vast majority of problems with `strlen` (or any of the other `str*` functions) come down to the fact that the string isn't terminated with a `\0` character<sup>(a)</sup>. This can cause the function to run off the end of (what you *think* is) the string and eventually access memory you're not allowed to.

For example:

```
char buff[] = { 'a', 'b' };
int x = strlen(buff);
```

may cause problems in that there's *no* guarantee there will be a terminator somewhere after that array.

What you need to do is look at the way in which this string is being constructed and find out *why* it has no terminator.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The real problem here is that it's not *actually* a string. A string is defined as a sequence of characters terminated by `\0`. If there's no terminator, it's a character array rather than a string, and therefore shouldn't be treated as the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code in question we can't tell you anything useful, but the *likely* cause is one of the following:

- you've passed an invalid pointer value to `strlen`;
- the string isn't properly terminated and you're wandering off into memory you don't own;

So, double check that particular `strlen` call, and make sure the argument is correct.